# Tabs in Jquery UI Dialog Not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I noticed that when I show up a modal dialog using Jquery UI in IE, once I reach the last control in the modal dialog, the tab focus goes out of the modal dialog and into the other parts of the browser. This is not the behavior in FireFox, wherein the focus loops back to the starting control of the modal dialog.

To see how this weird behavior happens, here is the official demo of Jquery UI and try tabbing both in FireFox and IE.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the order of fields to jump into using the `tabindex` property. But you cannot control afaik at which point to start over.

You can however assign an `accesskey` to submit your form, if this helps.